# OpenVPN cannot connect on one specific PC

Tags: linux, windows, openvpn

I cannot connect from one specific Win7 laptop to OpenVPN server.
And I can connect from another one Windows 7 computer.

It says *current state: connecting* and then stuck at that point.
I tested private/public keys - all looks correct.

Server is CentOS 7,  client - Win 7 x64.

Client log contains only the following lines:

```
Wed Jan 09 13:38:27 2019 us=154000 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Jan 09 13:38:27 2019 us=154000 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Wed Jan 09 13:38:27 2019 us=607000 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
```

Any ideas what can it be? Any assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is using of TCPOptimizer for Windows.
It is changed something in TCP stack options and OpenVPN fails.
I reverted default parameters and OpenVPN now is able to connect.

When I figure which exact options make troubles I will update this post.